# ReportService2010: create parent directories

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I wrote a PowerShell script to bulk upload RDL files to SSRS 2014.  I'm using the SOAP API exposed by `ReportService2010.aspx`:

```
$ssrsProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Credential $cred
$itemType = $ssrsProxy.GetItemType("/$reportFolder")
if($itemType -like "unknown")
{
    $ssrsProxy.CreateFolder($reportFolder, "/", $null)
}
```

This works if `$reportFolder` is `"foo"`, but not if it's `"foo/bar"`.  The error is:

> Exception calling "CreateFolder" with "3" argument(s): "The name of the item 'foo/bar' is not valid. The name must be less than 260 characters long. The name must not start with a slash character or contain a reserved character. Other restrictions apply. For more information on valid item names, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301650.

The URL in the message is invalid and redirects to a ["future resource"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd146365.aspx) page. The actual documentation for [`CreateFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.createfolder%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) says:

> You can use the forward slash character (/) to separate items in the full path name of the folder, but you cannot use it at the end of the folder name.

Am I interpreting this incorrectly, or does it not actually work as documented?

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty solution with no error handling. Use at your own risk.

```
$elements = $path.Split("/")
$parent = "/"
foreach($element in $elements)
{
    $name = ""
    if($parent.EndsWith("/"))
    {
        $name = "$parent$element"
    }
    else
    {
        $name = "$parent/$element"
    }
    $type = $ssrsProxy.GetItemType($name);
    if($type -like "unknown")
    {
        $ssrsProxy.CreateFolder($element, $parent, $null)
    }
    $parent = $name
}
```